# Изменение значений у объекта

Tags: ооп, php

Как можно у объекта изменить значение `QUANTITY`? Было 20, станет на один меньше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вижу 2 способа:

1. Определить свой класс корзины наследовав от WBasket, где и добавить Public функцию на изменение значения QUANTITY.
2. Можно прямо в существующем классе добавить свою функцию изменение значения QUANTITY.

Answer (score 0):

```
$object->QUANTITY -= 1;
```

Эмм... Я не понял вопроса?

**Добавлено**
Если QUANTITY - приватное свойство, то вариант только один: дописать в классе функцию, изменяющую это свойство. Наследование тут не прокатит, так как свойство закрыто.

```
public function changeQuantity($n){$this->QUANTITY += $n;}
```

Comment: вопрос зачемто изменили, там был дамп объекта класс WBasket, так вот QUANTITY - приватное свойство класса и так ты его не изменишь

Comment: Обновил ответ.